# И снова об этимологии

Tags: этимология

А каково происхождения слов "шеромыжник", "шеромыжничать"?

Answer (score 1):

По смысловой нагрузке схоже со словом "дармоед".

Происходить может как от немецкого "schmarotzer", так и французского "cher ami".

Answer (score 0):

Связывается с франц. cher ami «любезный друг» (от обращения солдат отступающей армии Наполеона о помощи, пощаде и т. д.).

Comment: Только в словарях все же 'шАромыжник', 'шАромыга', 'шАромыжничать'.

Comment: Вообще, мне попадалось и через А, и через Е. Не знаю, как правильнее.

Comment: Опираюсь на gramota.ru, www.slovari.ru. В словаре Фасмера статья тоже называется 'шаромыга', вариант через Е дается как второй.

Comment: Правильно называется и дaётся. Основной вариант - шаромыжник, только это не спрашивалось.

Comment: Поэтому только комментирую :-)